# UIButton won't generate randomly when score is added?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I am having a problem with my coding on Xcode. I am making an app in which a target appears, then you have to tap it, but the time allowed between each tap shortens gradually.

MY PROBLEM: whenever I try and make a UILabel update after a tap, the target goes back to it's original position on my view controller. I have all relevant code here:

```
-(IBAction)startButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    startButton.hidden = YES;
    Text.hidden = YES;

    targX = arc4random() %769;
    targY = arc4random() % 925;

    Target.center = CGPointMake(targX, targY);

    Target.hidden = NO;
}

-(IBAction)targetTapped:(id)sender {

    [Time invalidate];

    targX = arc4random() %769;
    targY = arc4random() % 925;

    [self scoreAdd:(id)sender];

    Target.center = CGPointMake(targX, targY);
    timeMax = 5 - (Score * 0.05);

    if (Score >= 90) {
        timeMax = 0.5;
    }

    Time = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeMax target:self selector:@selector(Lose:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}

-(void)Lose:(id)sender {

    Target.hidden = YES;
    Text.hidden = NO;

}


-(void)scoreAdd:(id)sender{

    Score = Score + 1;
    scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %li", Score];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

print 
targX = arc4random() %769;
targY = arc4random() % 925;

in both methods , check whether you are getting proper points. And check generated points lies with in device screen.